# Codeigniter 3 validation rule

Tags: validation, codeigniter-3

i have  a problem with form  validation rule:
This is controller:

```
   $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $vL = array(
        array(
            "field" => $this->input->post('username'),
            "rules" => "trim|required",
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'You must provide a %s.',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            "field" => $this->input->post('password'),
            "rules" => "trim|required",
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'You must provide a %s.',
            ),
        )
    );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($vL);
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        print "ok";
    } else {
        print "not ok"<br /><br />";
    }
```

View login:

```
                 echo form_open('', ['action' => '', 'id' => 'frmUsers', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'class' => 'form-signin']);


                 echo form_input(['name' => 'username', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'username', 'required' => 'required']);
                 echo form_input(['name' => 'password', 'class' => 'form-control', 'type' => 'password', 'required' => 'required']);
                 $data = array(
                     "type" => "submit",
                     "name" => "login",
                     "value" => "Sign in",
                     "class" => "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block",
                 );
                 echo form_submit($data);
```

I don't know where is the problem.Maybe because i don't have a label, but i'm not sure.Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

in the form validation array the `"field"` is for the name of the input not for it's value so `"field" => "username"` and `"field" => "password"` etc.